# Mpdf : Set 0 margin for page 1 only

Tags: php, mpdf

```
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf([
        'tempDir' => __DIR__ . '/temp'
    ]);
$mpdf->SetMargins(0, 0, 0); // will set it to 0 for all pages.
```

Is it possible to have 0 margins for page 1 of a PDF page and default margins for the rest of pages of the document ?

I'm currently testing this with Version 7.0.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you do not need automatic content overflow for page 1 and other pages, you can use [`AddPageByArray()`](https://mpdf.github.io/reference/mpdf-functions/addpagebyarray.html) method:

```
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf([]);

$mpdf->AddPageByArray([
    'margin-left' => 0,
    'margin-right' => 0,
    'margin-top' => 0,
    'margin-bottom' => 0,
]);

$mpdf->WriteHTML($html1); // first page

$mpdf->AddPageByArray([
    'margin-left' => '15mm',
    'margin-right' => '20mm',
    'margin-top' => '15mm',
    'margin-bottom' => '15mm',
]);

$mpdf->WriteHTML($html2); // other pages

// All other pages will then have margins of the second `AddPageByArray()` call.
```

In a case of content overflow from the first page, the next, automatically created page will also have zero margins.

---

Alternatively, you can set zero margins in the constructor and reset margins for following pages using [`<pagebreak>`](https://mpdf.github.io/reference/html-control-tags/pagebreak.html) pseudo-HTML tag:

```
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf([
    'margin_left' => 0,
    'margin_right' => 0,
    'margin_top' => 0,
    'margin_bottom' => 0,
]);

$html = 'Content of the first page
    <pagebreak margin-left="15mm" margin-right="15mm" margin-top="15mm" margin-bottom="20mm">
 Other content';   

$mpdf->WriteHTML($html1);
```

Comment: I used incorrect keys in #2, they should have underscores. Fixed this and tested, it works.