# mPDF : page-break-before:avoid;

Tags: php, mpdf

How do I get mPDF (version 7) to *not* page-break for the first **h1** ?
I'm already using AddPageByArray for [this reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49920397/mpdf-set-0-margin-for-page-1-only).

```
$mpdf->AddPageByArray([
    'margin-left' => '15mm',
    'margin-right' => '20mm',
    'margin-top' => '15mm',
    'margin-bottom' => '15mm',
]);

$html = "
<style type='text/css'>
h1 { page-break-before:always; }
h1:first-child { page-break-before:avoid; }
</style>
<h1>Heading 1</h1>";
```

The result is a blank 2nd page which I'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `:first-child` pseudo selector isn't a supported elements in mPDF ([see the supported CSS in the mPDF documentation](http://mpdf.github.io/css-stylesheets/supported-css.html)). Instead, you'll need to set an inline style on the first H1 (or give it a class and assign a class to the first H1)

```
$mpdf->AddPageByArray([
    'margin-left' => '15mm',
    'margin-right' => '20mm',
    'margin-top' => '15mm',
    'margin-bottom' => '15mm',
]);

$html = "
<style type='text/css'>
h1 { page-break-before:always; }
.no-page-break { page-break-before: inherit; }
</style>
<h1 style='page-break-before: inherit'>Heading 1</h1>
<h1 class='no-page-break'>Heading 1</h1>
<h1>Heading 1 on a new page</h1>";
```

Technically, `inherit` isn't a valid property in mPDF, but it unsets the `always` property.

Comment: In both cases I get an error :  Notice: Undefined index: current in /path/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/src/Tag/BlockTag.php on line 313

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this error today. I couldn't find any value for page-break-before that didn't throw up the mdf current index error besides **always**. The only way I could get this to work is to have a class for the first occurrence of the element I wanted to style and then a different class for the rest. Firstly, I did the following using SaaS (you could use straight CSS, but you would have to duplicate the styling across both classes, which is a bit messy):

```
%heading {
    /* add all of the heading styling here... */
}

.heading--first {
    @extend %heading;
}

.heading {
    @extend %heading;
    page-break-before: always;
}
```

Then the HTML looked a bit like this:

```
<h1 class="heading--first">..</h1>
<h1 class="heading">..</h1>
<h1 class="heading">..</h1>
```

Not a completely elegant solution, but I couldn't find a better workaround and it works. I hope this helps.