# PHP FPDF page break

Tags: php, fpdf

I am using PHP and FPDF to generate a PDF with a list of items. I have a loop and in the loop I have a verification with GetY() to check when will be the break. This work fine but on the first page, no. It's creating pages, but in the first page no break the texto to second page like others. What should I do?

```
[...]
if ($pdf->GetY() > 230) {
     $pdf->AddPage();
} 
endwhile;
```

Full Code:

```
if($_GET['print'] == 'ok'){
$idO = $_GET['id'];
require_once "assets/fpdf/fpdf.php";

$pdf = new FPDF( 'P', 'mm', 'A4' );

$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFillColor( 255, 255, 255 );
$pdf->SetDrawColor( 255, 255, 255 );
$pdf->AliasNbPages();
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true, 30);

$itens = get_field('itens', $idO);
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'categorias',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_key' => 'ordem',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'key' => 'status',
        'value' => 'ativo',
        'compare' => '='
    )
);

$query = new WP_Query($args);
$i=0;
while ($query->have_posts()):$query->the_post();
    foreach ($itens as $key => $value){
        if(get_field('categoria', $value) == get_the_ID()){
            $i++;

            $pdf->SetFont( 'Arial', 'B', 10 );

            if($i == 1){
                $pdf->MultiCell( 0, 10, utf8_decode(html_entity_decode(get_the_title($value))).':', 0, 'C', false );
                $imgWidth = 65;
                $f = get_field('principal', $value);
                $wI = get_field('_wp_attachment_metadata', get_field('foto'.$f, $value))['width'];
                $hI = get_field('_wp_attachment_metadata', get_field('foto'.$f, $value))['height'];

                $pY = ($imgWidth * $hI) / $wI;

                $pX = ($pdf->GetPageWidth() - $imgWidth) / 2;

                $img = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_field('foto'.$f, $value), 'full' )[0];
                $pdf->Image($img,$pX,$pdf->GetY(),$imgWidth);
                $pdf->Ln( $pY );

                $pdf->MultiCell( 0, 5, "Gabinete:", 0, 'L', false );
            } else{
                $pdf->MultiCell( 0, 5, utf8_decode(html_entity_decode(get_the_title($value))).':', 0, 'L', false );
            }

            if(get_field('modelo', $value) != ''){
                $pdf->Ln(2);
                $pdf->SetX(20);
                $pdf->SetFont( 'Arial', 'B', 10 );
                $pdf->MultiCell( 0, 5, "Modelo: ", 0, 'L', false );
                $pdf->SetX(25);
                $pdf->SetFont( 'Arial', '', 10 );
                $pdf->MultiCell( 0, 5, utf8_decode(get_field('modelo', $value)), 0, 'L', false );
            }
            if(get_field('fabricante', $value) != ''){
                $pdf->Ln(2);
                $pdf->SetFont( 'Arial', 'B', 10 );
                $pdf->SetX(20);
                $pdf->MultiCell( 0, 5, "Fabricante: ", 0, 'L', false );
                $pdf->SetX(25);
                $pdf->SetFont( 'Arial', '', 10 );
                $pdf->MultiCell( 0, 5, utf8_decode(get_field('fabricante', $value)), 0, 'L', false );
            }

            $pdf->SetX(20);
            $pdf->SetFont( 'Arial', 'B', 10 );
            $pdf->MultiCell( 0, 10, utf8_decode("Especificações Técnicas:"), 0, 'L', false );
            $pdf->SetX(25);
            $pdf->SetFont( 'Arial', '', 10 );
            $pdf->MultiCell( 0, 5, utf8_decode(html_entity_decode(get_field('descricao', $value))), 0, 'L', false );

            if($i > 1){
                if(get_field('exibir', $value) != ''){
                    $pdf->Ln( 2 );
                    $x=0;
                    foreach (get_field('exibir', $value) as $key2 => $value2){
                        $x++;
                        $imgWidth2 = 20;
                        $wtP = ($imgWidth2 * $x);
                        $pX2 = ($x == 1)?($pdf->GetX() + $wtP):($pdf->GetX() + $wtP + 5);
                        $img2 = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_field('foto'.$value2, $value), 'full' )[0];
                        $pdf->Image($img2,$pX2,$pdf->GetY(),$imgWidth2);
                    }
                    $pdf->Ln( 25 );
                }
            }

            if ($pdf->GetY() > 265) {
                $pdf->AddPage();
            }
        }
        $pdf->Ln( 2 );
    }
endwhile;
wp_reset_query();

$pdf->Output('', 'relatorio.pdf');
die();
```

}

Comment: did you tried to use `$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true, 10);`, the auto break page features ?

Comment: Yes, I do and this works, but not in the first page.

Comment: Hello Robson. Please provide more code for us to understand where the problem is.

Comment: I edited code.
Result: http://cdlservicos.com.br/relatorios.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Instead make an **IF()** and use **GETY ()** because you do not use **SETY ()**?
Creating a footer.

instead of:

```
if ($pdf->GetY() > 265) {
     $pdf->AddPage();
}
```

do that:

```
// set your value
$this->SetY(-15);
$pdf->AddPage();
```

Look at this official [example](http://www.fpdf.org/en/tutorial/tuto2.htm)

Comment: did you say to me create a footer with these codes and to remove IF(...)? Sorry man, I didn't understand

Comment: Yes because you make an IF to know the Y and create a new page? as in the example, this seems to be a good technique. And check if it works on your issue ... because I can not test.

Comment: If you can, check the moment result, please: http://cdlservicos.com.br/relatorios.pdf
Note that second page have a break in the description text, this is works in every pages, but in the first page, the text need continue, but is interrompedded and code create a new page. There is not a break, simplesly add a new page. I tried add this code in the footer, but don't gave a permission to it.

Comment: Yes, I saw it and I understood. I copied the official example and tested it with 10 pages and it worked correctly. Answer me ... what happens if you modify the $ pdf-> GetY ()> 265 line to a larger number ... eg 365?

Comment: Another way is for you to set the margin on the first page. I did not like it that way ... but check if works for you. Follow the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49920397/mpdf-set-0-margin-for-page-1-only

Comment: when I add a larger number, I haven't a problem with create new page, I have with the break. The text stop and don't continue in the next page, show the next data of loop. Exactly what happen, now, with the first page, the text is interromped and, in the new page, show the next data of loop.

Comment: The link that you sent me is for mpdf, fpdf I guess haven't other way to margin bottom, only "SetAutoPageBreak". I found options to top, left and right margins just

Comment: Well, I user the first page as a cover and the loop data starting at second page. It's works now. Thx dude

Answer (score 0):

seems that "SetAutoPageBreak" isn't work on the first page, only on the others. The code is creating pages, but don't breaking on the first